# Sql Server ambiguous query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

1) Totalplayers(player_id,player_name)

2) chess_player(chess_id,player_id)

3) tennis_player(tennis_id,player_id)

4) game(chess_id,tennis_id,date)

---

Now the game is between a chess player and a tennis player.

How can i retrieve data by SQL query in the form of :-

---

player_name(chess) | player_name(tennis) | date

---

eg:-                           TotalPlayers

```
           player_id        player_name

      1)    ply1            John

      2)    ply2            Rohn
```

---

```
                           Chess_Players

           chess_id        player_id

      1)    chess1           ply1
```

---

```
                           Tennis_Player

           chess_id        player_id

      1)    tennis1           ply2
```

---

```
                      Game

           chess_id        tennis_id            date

      1)    chess1           tennis1          12/12/2018
```

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
                       PLAYER_NAME(CHESS)    PLAYER_NAME(TENNIS)     DATE

```
                       JOHN                  ROHN                 12/12/2018
```

Comment: What did you try to achieve this?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: I have updated.Please check it.

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, or something else. Pick one - don't just spam tag whatever comes to mind.

Comment: i don't think it would make any difference because it is mostly same in all the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get thw two name store in the same table you can use the same table twice using different alias

```
select t1.player_name as chess_player_name, t2.player_name as tennis_player_name, 
from game
inner join chess_player cp on cp.chess_id = game.chess_id
inner join tennis_player tp on tp.tennis_id = game.tennis_id
inner join Totalplayers t1 = t1.player_id = cp_player_id
inner join Totalplayers t2 = t2.player_id = tp_player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> As the name of both chess and tennis players are stored in one table,
>   so how to retrieve their individual names separately in one row ??

You'd use the same table twice, but each of them would have a **different alias**.